# MPLAB XC8 interrupt routine doesn't get called for IOC (pic 16f877a) simulator

Tags: c, interrupt-handling, mplab

I have written some code, a simple program to try to increment a counter during an interrupt on [portbbits.rb7](/questions/tagged/portbbits.rb7). The program builds without error however a warning exists that:

> :: warning: (1273) Omniscient Code Generation not available in Free mode 
>   main.c:32: warning: (520) function "_Interrupt" is never called

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

#include <pic16f887.h>
#include <xc.h>

char counter = 0;
char dummy = 0;

void main(void) 
{
    TRISB = 0x80;           //Configure PORTB pin 7 to input
    TRISC = 0xOO;           //Configure PORTC to output

    INTCONbits.RBIF = 0;    //clear interrupt on change flag 
    INTCONbits.GIE =  1;    //enable global interrupts
    INTCONbits.RBIE = 1;    //enable port change interrupt

    while(1)
     {
        PORTC = counter;    //update PORTC with value of counter
     }
     return;
}

void Interrupt (void)
{
    INTCONbits.RBIF = 0;  //clear Interrupt on change flag
    dummy = PORTB;        //do a dummy read to clear IOC flag
    counter++;            //increment counter
}
```

On the snippets of code I've seen, people are usually testing their interrupts on hardware. However I don't have the hardware as yet, so trying to do some simulations and checking out stuff in the address registers etc.

I made the assumption that I would be able verify the interrupt routine with just software (see attached screen grabs).[File Registers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqI9M.jpg) [Counter Variable Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRZ9t.jpg)

So if anyone can point out my omission, or lead me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you think `Interrupt` will ever be called?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention that i can toggle PORTBbits.7 in the simulator. Therefore I expected that once I did that, the routine would have been called.

Comment: Hi Olaf, were you refering to the fact that I was missing the [tag:ISR] in the interrupt definition ? Well incase that wasnt what you were refering to, I have included it and I now have a clean build, however i still can not access the Interrupt Service Routine. any more hints ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the function qualifier `interrupt` to the definition of your interrupt service routine, so the compile knows it's a interrupt service routine and not a regular function, and perhaps rename the function itself so the name and qualifier are clearly seperated:

```
void interrupt ISR (void) //Added 'interrupt' qualifier and renamed function to 'ISR' for clarity.
{
    INTCONbits.RBIF = 0;  //clear Interrupt on change flag
    dummy = PORTB;        //do a dummy read to clear IOC flag
    counter++;            //increment counter
}
```

Comment: I read in a tutorial that it wasn't neccesary to do that so I hadn't tried. Will make that adjustment and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. that fixed one issue.

Comment: I added your change to my code and I have no errors or warnings on build, however I am now trying to figure out why I cant hit the break point in the ISR.

Comment: On what line did you put the breakpoint? You might also try putting a breakpoint on the PIC program memory view (the generated assembly) on program memory address 4, which is the hardwired interrupt vector.

Comment: Dummy = PORTB.  I checked the Port B register and  it alternates between 0x80 and 0x00 when i toggle PORTB bit 7. This is good. However "Dummy" and "counter" don't get updated since the Isr is never executed.

Comment: Just tried your code in my MPLABX simulator. I had to remove the line `#include <pic16f887.h>` and add the `interrupt` qualifier and then it worked perfectly. It triggers the breakpoint on `dummy = PORTB` on every stimulus of PB7.

Comment: Really. just did the same and still no dice. I'm running v3.45.

Comment: It appears you inserted a line of code that mine didn't. Your program must have had a line to  enable IOC bit 7. I found that out in another forum. Thanks for the help though.